# Requiring app variable from electron inside function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, electron

I am trying to assign the app object from electron but it returns as undefined. I have tried to debug this but i cant for the love of god find out what is wrong. Here is a snippet of my logic

```
const ClientBootstrapper = function() {

  this.App = null;

  this.Init = function() {
      const app = require('electron').app;  
      console.log(app); // undefined???
      return // for debug
      this.App = app;
    });
});

module.exports = new ClientBootstrapper();
```

Why does this not work and how should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this failed is because i forgot to switch the start script from using node. Requiring electron in a node results in the path to electron instead.